# javascript add checkbox-checked values with the use of custom attribute

Tags: javascript

I found this existing [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6NJ8e/13/) from other questions. My question is, how do I put custom attribute in this code?

I have tried it like this but didn't work

```
<input value="50" othervalue="800" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Instagram

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = $(this).attr('othervalue') * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
    }
}
```

Comment: `inputs[i].dataset.mywhatever = "foo"`

Comment: i don't understand, where do I put this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

e.g.

On the input

```
<input value="50" data-othervalue="800" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
```

The javascript:

```
var add = this.dataset.othervalue * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, if you really want to use the `othervalue` attribute and not a standard `data-` attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/6NJ8e/272/

```
let totalCost = 0;
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.onchange = function() {
    const thisInputCharge = input.value * (
      input.getAttribute('othervalue')
      ? parseInt(input.getAttribute('othervalue'))
      : 1
    );
    if (this.checked) totalCost += thisInputCharge;
    else totalCost -= thisInputCharge;
    total.textContent = totalCost;
    total1.textContent = totalCost;
  }
})
```

(Made some other changes, too - it's often better to iterate directly with forEach, to avoid `this` references when you already have a variable name, and to store data in a variable rather than in HTML on the page)